# Can JS be used to display a new dropdown already filled by php mysql?

Tags: php, javascript

I know that PHP is server-side and JS is client side, I've done some research but haven't exactly found what I was looking for.

So what I'd like to know is if it is possible to use Javascript to display PHP code?

Scenario:

I have a drop down list already on the page being updated from a database

(quick example)

```
php while($row...) {
    <option><?php echo $row["number"]; ?></option>
}
```

and I am using Javacript to display a new drop down list when a button is clicked

```
<script language="javascript">
var i = 1;
function changeIt()
{
my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br><select><option name='mytext'+ i></option></select>"
i++;
}
</script>
```

This works but what I'd like to be able to do is have this new drop down list appear pre filled.

Is this possible to have these 2 items work together?? If so how? Or would this require a page reload each time since php loads before it reaches the user (and how again..)?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you have PHP generate a hidden select and just show it with js? I guess my question is more: how exactly does the first select determine the second? Show an example of what would be in the first and what type of selection would equal what stuff in the new select?

Comment: AJAX is the answer in this case

Comment: You could always make an ajax request when the button is pressed to a php file that in turn will return the new select list to your client.

Comment: You want to load data from the server based on the first selection?

Comment: The first select doesn't determine the second or third or fourth etc. I just want to display a new select (displaying the same thing) each time a new select box is requested. It could be possible to have it generate the PHP code and have it hidden but the problem is that it can't be determined how many lists will be required. Something 1 or 2 and other times 9 or 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example uses `jQuery` to make an ajax call to `your-script.php`, which in turn returns the html for a select list:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // event handler for click on the button control
   $('#your-button').click(function() {
     // make ajax request
     $.ajax({
       url:"your-script.php",
       success:function(e) {
         // insert html for the select control
         $('#control-panel').html(e);
       }
    });
   });
});

<div id="control-panel">replace this with select control</div>
<input type="button" id="your-button" />
```

Here is the contents of the `your-script.php` file:

```
<?php
  print '<select><option value="1">1</option></select>';
?>
```

Comment: So I've got everything pretty much working which is great but theres now 1 last thing I'm not 100% sure on. When I now hit the 'button' it will display the drop down list pre filled (perfect) but how can I make it so that if I click the button again a 2nd drop down appears, or a third and so on. My original code had my_div = my_div +(...) to have each new box appear. How can I achieve this in the AJAX code?

Comment: Of course you need to return something different through ajax and then your could use the `append()` method like: `$('#control-panel').append(e);` I think. Read up on ajax and jQuery if that's what you're using.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Like I said a good think is to always refer to the documentation for the things you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

You can load data from the server using ajax. A good and very common way to do so it to use jQuery to do it.

Check out this example: [jQuery Ajax Tutorial](http://www.phptutorialforbeginners.com/2013/01/jquery-ajax-tutorial-and-example-of.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Quite helpful and easy to understand